# Relationship between null space and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was attempting a true/false question from a linear algebra textbook and one of the questions was

> Suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(λ) = λ^3(λ − 2)(λ + 3)^2$ . Then the null space of $A$ can be at most $2$–dimensional.

The answer was given as false with the explanation being that the multiplicity of the $0$ eigenvalue gives the possible dimensions of the null space. In this case, since the multiplicity is $3$, the maximum dimension of null space can be $3$. Hence, the statement is false.

However, I do not understand how the multiplicity of $0$ eigenvalue relates to the null space. Does that mean that if a characteristic polynomial does not have $0$ as its root, the corresponding matrix will have an empty null space (besides the $0$ vector)? Do the other eigenvalues not have anything to do with the null space? What exactly is the relationship between eigenvalues and the null space?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the explanation tries to say that the multiplicity of $0$ is $3$, the maximal among all eigen-values, so $3$ is the maximal possible dimension of an eigen-space.

Comment: The explanation is this: "False. The eigenvalue λ = 0 has multiplicity 3, and hence has eigenspace of dimension 1, 2, or 3. But this is exactly the nullspace of A." So I assumed that they are specifically only talking about the 0 eigenvalue

Comment: The dimension of the nullspace corresponds to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0. In particular, A has all non-zero eigenvalues if and only if the nullspace of A is trivial (null(A)={0}). You can then use the fact that dim(Null(A))+dim(Col(A))=dim(A) to deduce that the dimension of the column space of A is the sum of the multiplicities of the non-zero eigenvalues

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, the dimension of the null-space (or the kernel) of $A$ cannot exceed the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of eigenvalues/eigenvectors, we have $Ax=\lambda x$. In the special case of $\lambda = 0$ it becomes $Ax=0$. This means the null space of $A$ is the space that is spanned by the eigenvectors of $0$ eigenvalue.

In your example the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ eigenvalue is 3. However, we don't know the geometric multiplicity - that is the number of linearly independent eigenvectors. But we know that it is at least 1 and cannot exceed the algebraic multiplicity. So the dimension of null space is between 1 and 3 inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

λ=0 has a multiplicity of 3 in the CP. Therefore the nullspace can be of dimension 3 at-most. Knowing the exact multiplicity is to be done by finding the vector space spanned by the eigenvalue.